# Play audio sound when component re-render and on initial render - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio

I'm building an interactive app, where users can 'ping' each other by choice.

on every so-called 'ping' I'm making a notification sound to let the user know he has a new message.

i have a component called BellNotifcation :

```
import soundFile from "../../assets/sharp.mp3";

const BellNotification = ({
  askingUserDisplayNameArray,
  openInvitationModal
}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const audio = new Audio(soundFile);

    const audioPromise = audio.play();

    if (audioPromise !== undefined) {
      audioPromise
        .then(_ => {
          console.log("played");
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.info(err);
        });
    }
  }, [askingUserDisplayNameArray]);
```

I'm currently having 2 problems on different browsers  :

1.on firefox and chrome the user needs to interact with the browser first (click), and if not I'm getting this error :

`The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission`

after searching the web , and trying different solutions nothing seems to work . is there a 'hack' for this problem?

2.on safari I'm always getting the above error message (on every 'ping'), regardless of the user interacted with the browser or not.

Comment: Did you try https://howlerjs.com/ ? I had good experiences

Comment: worked like a charm, it's delaying the sound effect on user interaction , and working great on safari , thank you @Julian